# Python Google appengine 'Attachment' object does not support indexing

Tags: google-app-engine

Since sometime after 3pm EST on January 9th I am getting 
TypeError: 'Attachment' object does not support indexing errors when trying to access the data portion of an email attachment:

```
            attach = mail_message.attachments.pop()
        encodedAttachment = attach[1]
```

The format of the emails I am processing has not changed in that time, and this code worked flawlessly up until then

Comment: Hi, did you log an issue for this?

Answer (score 3):

The latest version (1.8.9) has introduced an Attachment class that is returned now instead of the (filename content) tuple that was returned previously. The class does implement `__iter__`, so unpacking works exactly the same:

```
filename, content = attachment
```

But it doesn't implement `__getitem__`, so accessing via index as you're doing will cause the error you're seeing. It's possible that creating an issue will get the code changed to be completely backwards-compatible, but the practical thing would be to change your code.